# How to Drag a bitmap over another Bitmap on Canvas with Surfaceview in Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I am new to using **Canvas** and **SurfaceView** in Android.

I am trying to implement a application with a *canvas* using *Surfaceview*,and I want to drag bitmaps on that view.I am able to drag any no.of Bitmaps.

I have 2 different sizes in Bitmaps as shown in below image :

[IMAGE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ZBgANt7zWKcktnbEprWTVwWkk/view?usp=sharing)

**REquirement**

1. Big size (Bmp1) Bitmap - 1
2. Small and equal in dimension/resolution Bitmaps(A,B,C,D,E.....) - n(No restriction in number)

3.I have to drag A/B/C/... to Bmp1.And when any small Bmp reached to Bmp1 and if it is in surroundings of its relative port(A/B/C/....) a connection should establish.

4.So,i have to drag any BMP over any other BMP

***PROBLEM*** :

1. While I am dragging a small Bitmap to big Bitmap when they come to close they small is overlapping on big at center and unable to drag small Bitmap separately until move big one.
2. When two small bitmaps are coming to close upper one is overlapping on lower drawing bitmap and unable to separate them.

How to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normal collision detection ... use a for loop to iterate through the other bitmaps positions ...in this loop just check

if(Math.abs(draggedBMP.posX-otherBMP.posX)< draggedBMP.width/2+otherBMP.width/2&&Math.abs(draggedBMP.posY-otherBMP.posY)< draggedBMP.height/2+otherBMP.height/2) Log.e("fatal","overlapping...world will explode");

or something like that..."AABB"<- google that

Comment: But i have huge no.of bitmaps. so,if i use for loop it may effect to performance...

Comment: so what? you just have to check the one bitmap you are dragging if it's colliding...and you cant have that many bitmaps dude...10 000 iteration are ok...more than ok i guess....btw yif you have too many you are in danger to get an OOM exception

Comment: what you suggested was useful for whether two bitmaps are overlapping or not.But i need solution for avoiding overlap.  That mean's If **BmpA is coming to BmpB then BmpB can drag over the BmpA**. This is my requirement.

Comment: ahhh ok it wasnt so clear in your post...so give them a z-order: two are enough...when you drag a bitmap give it the z-order of 1 all others have 0...so when you are drawing them just ask which zorder they have if 0 just draw them if 1 keep them in mind dont draw it but wait till all others are drawn and draw it as the last one

Comment: sorry, i am not getting you can you elaborate clearly if possible.

Comment: your problem is that the bitmaps(images) you are dragging are overdrawn by other bitmaps right? thats because of the order you are drawing them if you draw bitmapA first and then bitmapB and you start dragging bitmapA then bitmapB is overlapping bitmapA becuse of the order in which you draw them right? just make sure to draw the bitmap you are dragging right now as the last one...furthermore if you want the bitmap that you have dragged above an other bitmap to not be overlapped after releasing it you have to use an array where you sort the bitmaps in the right order to be drawn

Comment: i would recommend to use an arraylist at the moment when you click on a bitmap you just remove it from the array list just to add it right after you removed it so this bitmap is the last to be drawn when you iterate through that arraylist to draw the bitmaps...voila the bitmap you are dragging will be the last to be drawn and no other bitmap will overlap it until you choose another one to drag....understandable enough?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.But i have images in two sizes. one in one big BMP and rest of all are in same in size.So if two bmps with same size come closer those are overlapping and i am unable to detach those.

Comment: Please update the question with the various clarifications. As written it's unclear what you're asking, and not everyone will wade through the comments.

Comment: @fadden : Done... please suggest a solution for my problem

Comment: hey what does your app do exactly? is it a photogallery,a game or something like that? be more specific. I can only give you tips, if i know wich behaviour you are expecting from your app...tell us what behaviour you want please so we can help you out...and tell us a bit about your system what your bitmaps are for...does the small bitmap get lost behind the big while dragging or only after releasing and does the small one jump in some given positions, do you have a layout how the bitmaps are presented on the screen like a grid?

Comment: **@IljaKO** complete details added